# Replace \" with " in string

Tags: c#, string, replace

I have a string:

```
var a = "some text \"";
```

I want to replace `\"` with `"`.

`a.Replace("\"", '"');` => *The best overloaded method match for 'string.Replace(string, string)' has some invalid arguments*

`a.Replace("\"", """);` => *Newline in constant*

finally I want to obtain `"some text"`

Comment: Ooh, there's a mistake somewhere. \" is already escaped to ". If your string is `some text \"`, the result you'll get when using it will be `some text "`

Comment: Does your source string _really_ have `\"` in it or is that just what the debugger shows?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to escape your string, you are looking for:

```
a.Replace("\\\"", "\"");
```

That should do it!

**NOTE**

Please note - just calling replace creates a NEW STRING VALUE it does not edit the original string. If you want to use this string you can do the replace inline or you can assign back to the original value like so:

```
a = a.Replace("\\\"", "\"");
```

That could also be another issue you are having!

Comment: @Alex Is that in the debugger? The debugger shows the string as escaped not the string that would actually print. Try printing the string to your console or you can show it in the text viewer by pressing the magnifier.

Comment: @Alex As said previously and in a few other comments - the `\ "` that the debugger is showing is the escaped version of the string. Click on the tiny magnifying glass on the right to open the actual string (which just has a double quote).

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be confused by C#'s [escaping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) rules. The literal `"some text \""` has the value `some text "`. If you look at this string in the VS debugger, it will show the C# literal that produces the value: `"some text \""`. If you print it, you'll see its value is actually `some text "`.

If the value is actually `some text \"`, which could be represented by `"some text \\\""` or `@"some text \"""`, then what you really want is this:

```
var b = a.Replace("\\\"", "\"");
```

I suspect that your string is actually already what you want, though: `some text "`

Comment: @Alex your string does not actually contain a \. That's just how it appears in the debugger, because that's what you can type as C# source to get the same string.

Answer (score 1):

You can use verbatim strings introduced with `@`. In verbatim strings double quotes are escaped by doubling them and the backslashes don't work as escape characters any more:

```
string result = a.Replace(@"\""", @"""");
```

Compared to normal strings, you still have to escape the double quote (`"`), but not the backslash (`\`).

Of course you can combine both solutions:

```
string result = a.Replace(@"\""", "\"");
```

See also: [What character escape sequences are available?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/12/what-character-escape-sequences-are-available.aspx)

Comment: I almost wrote up this solution but I'm not sure its more readable for double quotes. Still -- it does work!

Answer (score 0):

You need some escaping! Use this:

```
a.Replace("\\\"", "\"");
```

Comment: This `a.Replace("\\"", '"');` shouldn't compile

Comment: This takes either two strings or two characters

Comment: but now your answer is just a duplicate the other exiting answers.

Answer (score 0):

'\' This will treated as escape character in C# you need to use double quote to replace it with.
see below snippet

```
string afterreplace = txtBox1.Text.Replace("\\\"", "\"");
```